# Chart highlighting in the highcharts javascript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So basically I'm using the **Highcharts** JavaScript library to render a very simple line graph to my HTML5 page. The chart represents the volume of tweets I've crawled from Twitter.

So my question is for anyone who has a fair idea of what Highcharts is capable of. I know you're able to highlight a section of the chart and have it zoom in. Is it possible to have the chart recognize the start and end time I've highlighted and give it back to me.

I wanna be able to query my database and pull out all the tweets between the two times and render them to the page. Anyone any idea if that's feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can achieve it by catching afterSetExtremes function.

http://jsfiddle.net/JzEnV/

```
 events:{
                afterSetExtremes:function(){
                    alert(this.min);
                    alert(this.max);
                }
            }
```

If you would like to get dates, then you can use dateFormat() 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat()